# Transaction not being honored MySql .NET connector with multiple queries

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I've tried researching this topic but it doesn't make sense.  I have a bit of code trying to execute an UPDATE query and then loop through another set of INSERT queries.  The second query errors because I've omitted the parameters (this is intentional at the moment to induce an error).  The UPDATE still gets committed even though it should not...

Here's the code....

```
using (MySqlConnection con = existingCon.Clone())
{
con.Open();

MySqlParameter paramTimeStamp;
MySqlParameter paramFileNo;
MySqlParameter paramDescription;
MySqlParameter paramComment;
MySqlParameter paramUserInfo;
MySqlParameter paramPaymentType;
MySqlParameter paramSeriesLink;
MySqlParameter paramOriginalSubmitDate;

using (MySqlTransaction transact = con.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        using (
            MySqlCommand cmd =
                new MySqlCommand(
                    "UPDATE Payments "
                        + "SET strStatus = 'processing-preupload' "
                        + "WHERE strStatus = 'processing-prepost';",
                    con))
        {
            cmd.Transaction = transact;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transact.Rollback();
        throw;
    }

    foreach (Payment payment in payments)
    {
        try
        {
            using (
                MySqlCommand cmd =
                    new MySqlCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO Activity "
                            + "(dtmTimeStamp, strFileNumber, strDescription, strComment, "
                                + "strUserInfo, strPaymentType, dtmSeriesLink, dtmOriginalSubmitDate) "
                            + "VALUES (@paramTimeStamp, @paramFileNo, @paramDescription, @paramComment, "
                                + "@paramUserInfo, @paramPaymentType, @paramSeriesLink, @paramOriginalSubmitDate);",
                        con))
            {
                paramTimeStamp = new MySqlParameter("@paramTimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
                paramFileNo = new MySqlParameter("@paramFileNo", payment.strFileNumber);
                paramDescription = new MySqlParameter("@paramDescription", description);
                paramComment = new MySqlParameter("@paramComment", comment);
                paramUserInfo = new MySqlParameter("@paramUserInfo", userInfo);
                paramPaymentType = new MySqlParameter("@paramPaymentType", PAYMENT_TYPE);
                paramSeriesLink = new MySqlParameter(
                    "@paramSeriesLink",
                    payment.strSeriesLink_corrected);
                paramOriginalSubmitDate = new MySqlParameter(
                    "@paramOriginalSubmitDate",
                    payment.strSubmitDate_corrected);

                cmd.Transaction = transact;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transact.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }

    transact.Commit();
}
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: it shouldn't affect the outcome, but you should only need a single `try`/`catch` here...

Comment: You are correct.  This code was my latest attempt which was to invoke the rollback manually if for some reason the transaction was getting committed anyway.

Comment: So it does execute that second "transact.Rollback();"?  Try not assigning the command to the transact multiple times.

Comment: @Blam it is perfectly normal to want to use a transaction from multiple separate commands; that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes but you still only need to assign the command to the transaction once.

Comment: Yes, this was trying to modify two different tables.  One manages financial activity, while the other logs an action pertaining to the first.  If one query fails, all needed to fail gracefully.

Comment: @Blam if they are unrelated command instances, no

Comment: @MarcGravell You are correct I did not notice the new commands

Comment: Why are you creating so many new commands rather than just reuse one command?

Comment: This is probably a bad assumption but I was under the impression that unlike C++ where pointer loss is bad for memory leaks, "new" didn't have the same performance impact in C#.  Yes, it could be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thoughts; firstly:

> In MySQL, only InnoDB and BDB (BerkeleyDB) table formats support transactions. Other standard storage engines ignore transactions and can not rollback data modifications.

So... what table format are you using?

Secondly: you could try using the overload that accepts an `IsolationLevel`, just to be explicit - but I suspect the table-format is the real problem here.

Comment: MYISAM.  Bingo.  Funny thing, though.  It appeared to work at one point, but stopped again.  Figures the one place I don't look for answers...  thanks Marc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help someone.

Some old versions of the connector (around 6.4.4 I think) automatically rolled back the transaction after a query error. This doesn't seem to be the case with the latest version (6.9.6).

"*Funny thing, though. It appeared to work at one point, but stopped again*" makes me wonder.